# Reverse proxying only a specific URL

Tags: apache2, proxy

I have a web server at www.ourcompany.com running Apache2. Using the proxy modules, I am able to (for example) get 172.16.0.5, an internal IP device, to be accessed on www.ourcompany.com/device.

The trouble is that anyone can play with or explore the device using strings sent to www.ourcompany.com/device/change/settings/here.html. I'd like the reverse proxy to only work for a specific URL; www.ourcompany.com/device/you/must/use/this while anything else will be rejected if requested.

Is there a setting that can be used to do this, or is it a simple rewrite condition placed in the virtualhost for the site under sites-enabled? What is the simplest, most maintainable way to sanitize requests to the internal device through the reverse proxy?

Running Apache2 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

The [`ProxyPass`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) directive accepts 3 different contexts: server config, virtual host, directory.

Because is is valid in a directory context, may be used inside `<Directory>`, `<Location>`, `<Files>`, and `<Proxy>` containers in the server configuration files, subject to the restrictions outlined in Configuration Sections.

In your case, you can use a [`Location`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location) container to specify the allowed locations.

```
<Location /device>
ProxyPass ...
</Location>
```

Comment: So you're saying that I could use something like 
<Location /device/you/must/use/this>
ProxyPass 172.16.0.5
</Location>
To specify that only requests to that location would be reverse-proxied?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can learn more by reading the Apache documentation.